# How do the $node modifications in hook_node_presave persist?

Tags: hooks

I was looking at [`hook_node_presave()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) and I tested it out and it works as described. The thing I'm puzzled about is that it doesn't take the `$node` parameter by reference, nor does it return anything from the function, however when I modify `$node` in this hook, the changes get saved. I'm really confused. Can anyone shed some light and make sense of this? How do I implement something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objects are (mostly) [passed by reference in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php). The `$node` variable is a `stdClass` object so any changes you make will be reflected on the original object in memory.

You don't need to do anything special to implement this yourself, just accept an object as an argument to a function as usual and let PHP take care of the rest.